# Idiomatic way for using numbers in Enum items

Tags: rust

What's the best way to represent

```
enum Resolution {
    2k,
    4k,
}
```

?

Enums don't seem to like raw identifiers as the documentation for [identifiers](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/identifiers.html) show.

```
 + r#2k
error: found invalid character; only `#` is allowed in raw string delimitation: 2
```

```
 + r"2k"
error: expected identifier, found `r"2k"`
```

```
 + r#"2k"#
error: expected identifier, found `r#"2k"#`
```

Comment: You'll need to start with a letter unless you want to fight it with `r#`. `R2k` would be fine.

Comment: needs to be "2k" to match a interface i want to provide an alternative for.

Comment: Well, we all want things we can't have. You can `impl From<&str>` to handle `"2k".into()`.

Comment: @gcb, the identifier can't be "2k", simple as that. Your comment regarding "interface" suggests you are looking at the serialized values. You can [rename](https://serde.rs/variant-attrs.html) these variants to other strings, but for the _identifier_ it is what it is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Raw identifiers only allow for certain (not all) keywords to be used as identifiers. All identifiers (*raw* or not) [need to](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/identifiers.html) start with an [`XID_START`](https://www.unicode.org/reports/tr31/tr31-37.html#D1), which includes

> *uppercase letters, lowercase letters, titlecase letters, modifier letters, other letters, letter numbers*

but not

> *nonspacing marks, spacing combining marks, **decimal number**, connector punctuation*

Therefor, "2k" can't be a valid identifier, no matter how you slice or dice it.

You can use a [prefix](https://docs.rs/libc/latest/libc/constant.B921600.html), or just use natural language (e.g. `TWO_K`)